# Magento 1.9 Multi Store different super attribute values

Tags: import, attributes, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have 2 stores and create CF products using import. How do I control the super attribute values for the second store as they are different to the values used for the default store?

Comment: I can share examples of the csv import files that I use.

Comment: what attributes do you exactly mean? your question lacks on details

Comment: Here is a paste from my CSV2, which links the simples to the CF and adds any uplifts.  sku _super_products_sku _super_attribute_code _super_attribute_option _super_attribute_price_corr
TS1476/CF TS1476/SM25-L fabric_base Life 2
 TS1476/SM25-L fabric_base Life 0
 TS1476/SM25-304 fabric_base Titan 4
 TS1476/SM25-304 fabric_base Titan 0 You'll see for SKU there are two rows, one for each store, but the second entry isnt effective, it does give a zero value uplift to the second store. This store is set to default values &uses the uplift as per the first store. I can amend on the frontend but..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the proper values to the attributes needed.

Let's say an attribute *shoe_size*.

For EU store will have values: 40, 41, 42, 43, 44 and 45
For USA store will have values: 8, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5 and 11.

So attribute *shoe_size* must have all those values included.

If you don't want to show all those values in product page or filters you can modify this in frontend displaying what you want or create two attributes: shoe_size_eu and shoe_size_usa.

Regards.